# Smallest eigenvalue of sum of two unbounded operators

Tags: operator-theory, perturbation-theory

Suppose $T,S:D(\mathcal H)\to \mathcal H$ are two unbounded operators with discrete spectrum consisting eigenvalues    $0<\lambda_1(T)\leq\lambda_2(T)\leq\dots$ and $0<\lambda_1(S)\leq\lambda_2(S)\leq\dots$.  Moreover assume that $T+S$ also has discrete spectrum and that

**Q.** How large  $\lambda_1(T+S)$ can be compared to $\lambda_1(T)$ and $\lambda_1(S)$?

Comment: You could write the Question as: "Suppose $T,S:D(\mathcal H)\to D(\mathcal H)$ are two unbounded Hermetian operators with discrete spectrum and least eigenvalues $0$. If $T+S$ also has discrete spectrum, how large can it's least eigenvalue be?" (Just adding constants to $S,T$.) Also, did you mean $D(\mathcal H)\to \mathcal H$ ?

Comment: Also, do you know the answer for $2 \times 2$ matrices?

Comment: Yes, edited it. I'm so used to copy-pasting in LaTex.

Comment: You have a better chance of getting an Answer if you write the Question in the simplest possible way. If you agree that the answer follows from that of the special case I have stated then you should ask that. Anyone who could answer knows that discrete eigenvalues can be arranged in ascending sequence, so you don't need to write that out.

Answer (score 0):

I answer this question, which I think implies the answer to your question:

> Suppose $T,S$ are possibly unbounded Hermitian operators in a Hilbert space with discrete spectrum and least eigenvalues $0$. If $T+S$ also has discrete spectrum, how large can it's least eigenvalue be?

In the case of $2 \times 2$ matrices you can solve the problem explicitly.

For general operators you can solve the Rayleigh-Schrodinger equation, which is non-linear and involves calculating the inverse of one of the operators (With discrete spectrum, calculating the inverse not a problem.).

If you want an upper bound you can construct approximants to the
eigenvalue by simply
choosing an arbitrary sequence of vectors which spans the Hilbert space
and minimizing $\frac{(\psi , (T+S) \psi}{(\psi,\psi)}$
 in the subspace spanned by the
first $n$ vectors.

In special cases there may be explicit solutions to the eigenvalue problem . In one case ($x^4$ anharmonic oscillator) there are approximants from below.